# What's wrong with my AsyncTask? Doesn't seem to be executing properly

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to run an AsyncTask to return results from a REST API, but the code that I've written does not seem to be running.  When I run through the app to the point where the AsyncTask should be run, nothing is displayed.  There are no errors, the data just never displays.  Additionally, when I entered created some `log.i`s to display the data being returned, nothing showed in the LogCat window.

The following is the related code:

```
public class PlaceActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_URL = "url";
public static final String GEO = "geo";
public static final LatLng LOCATION = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);

private GoogleMap mMap;
protected Factual factual = new Factual("xyz", "xyz"); //new Factual code
private TextView resultText = null; //new Factual code

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place);
    setupActionBar();
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        String name = extras.getString(EXTRA_URL);
        String geo = extras.getString(GEO);
        Log.i("geo", geo); //currently from_user
        Log.i("name", name); //currently text
        TextView venueLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vLocation); //was detailsText
        //view.setText(name + " " + geo);
        TextView venName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vName);
        venueLocation.setText(geo);
        venName.setText(name);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        factualQuery(); //new Factual code
    }
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    //Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            //do things to the map
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOCATION).title(EXTRA_URL));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION,15));
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}

public void factualQuery() {
    resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
    FactualRetrievalTask task = new FactualRetrievalTask();

    double latitude = 34.06018; //set programmatically
    double longitude = -118.41835; //set programmatically
    int meters = 500; //have a default and then set programmatically if needed?
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }


    Query query = new Query()
    .within(new Circle(latitude, longitude, meters))
    .field("cuisine").equal("Italian")
    .sortAsc("$distance")
    .only("name", "address", "tel");

    task.execute(query);
}

public class FactualRetrievalTask extends AsyncTask<Query, Integer, List<ReadResponse>> {

    @Override
    protected List<ReadResponse> doInBackground(Query... params) {
        List<ReadResponse> results = Lists.newArrayList(); 
        for (Query q : params) {
            results.add(factual.fetch("restaurants-us", q));
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ReadResponse> responses) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (ReadResponse response : responses) {
            for (Map<String, Object> restaurant : response.getData()) {
            String name = (String) restaurant.get("name");
            Log.i("name", name);
            String address = (String) restaurant.get("address");
            Log.i("address", address);
            String phone = (String) restaurant.get("tel");
            Log.i("tel", phone);
            Number distance = (Number) restaurant.get("$distance");
            sb.append(distance + " meters away: "+name+" @ " +address + ", call "+phone);
            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }  
        }
        resultText.setText(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

}

The `log.i` in `onPostExecute()` dont seem to be showing anything, which leads me to believe that it's not being executed.  Weird thing is that this code ran previously in a different project without any issues.

I was thinking it could be an issue related to dependencies (as that's been a problem around this code), but as I said, I'm not getting any errors.  Could dependencies still be an issue?  Does anything look strange?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't seem to see anything strange - are you sure the queries are returning something?

Comment: No, I'm not.  What's the best way to determine if they are?

Comment: Try it without Async to test if the code actually works.

Comment: Do a `Log.i (responses.length())` before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing in the emulator? If yes, the emulator will not give you location by default, you have to provide it coordinates, that it will then feed to your app. See http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#geo
You can try to run it on the device, and see if it runs your network fetch.

Comment: No I'm testing on an HTC Wildfire with Android 2.3.4, connecting via wifi.  I started doing this because of the maps portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

At first, add some Log.d in doInBackground() to check if the aynctask is blocked by network.
And there is any other aynctask running before? The AsyncTask will only use single thread at default, so it will be blocked by other Asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with dependencies.  I tried the older project that previously didn't work, and all of a sudden it started to work.  I matched my current project with the dependencies from the other project and that resolved the issue.  I was initially hesitant to do so because I was getting build errors with the previous project and its dependencies, but I removed what was causing that and now I think I'm good.

Can someone explain to me, though, why dependencies would solve the problem, but I wouldn't get errors telling me that certain methods/variables were missing (i.e. NullPointer, NoSuchMethod, etc)?